# ASP.net MVC Error: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I am trying add Authentication where a user details will be verified by the system. However, I am having multiple errors.

Controller class, I added the following code:

```
public ActionResult ForgotLoginId()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ForgotLoginId(Testing ForgotLIDAuthentication)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using(SUPRTestingDBEntities2 db = new SUPRTestingDBEntities2())
                {
                    var obj = db.SUPRTesting.Where(a => a.EmailID.Equals(ForgotLIDAuthentication.EmailID) && a.TaxID.Equals(ForgotLIDAuthentication.TaxID)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        Session["LoginID"] = obj.EmailID.ToString();
                        Session["TaxID"] = obj.TaxID.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("UserAuthentication");
                    }
                }          
            }
            return View(ForgotLIDAuthentication);
        }

        public ActionResult LIDAuthentication() 
/*This is where I am getting the error CS0161   'CorporationController.LIDAuthentication()': not all code paths return a value*/

        {
            if (Session["LoginID"] != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                RedirectToAction("ForgotLoginId");
            }
        }
```

View, I added the following code:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationTesting.Models.Testing>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Corporation Registration";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("LIDAuthentication", "Corporation", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <div style="border: 1px solid red">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}
<body>
    <div style="height: 30px; width: 20%; font-size: large; text-align: center; margin-left: 40%; margin-right: 40%; margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom: 46px; background-color: deepskyblue; color:white" class="auto-style9">
        <b>Forgot Login ID</b>
    </div>
</body>
<body>
    <form style="height: 475px; width: 50%; text-align: left; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%; margin-top: 10%; margin-bottom: 46px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-color:black">
        <span style="margin-left:10%"></span>
        <label for="Label1" style="width:20%; color:red; font-weight:normal !important">* Required Entry</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-left:10%"></span>
        <label for="Label5" style="width:20%">Email Address:</label>
        <label for="label6" style="color:red"><b>*</b></label>
        <span style="margin-left:9%"></span>
        <textarea asp-for="EmailId" style="width:50%; border-color: black" required>@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.EmailID)</textarea>
<text>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.EmailID)</text>
```

In the above two line, I am having the following error: 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'EmailID' and no accessible extension method 'EmailID' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
        <span style="margin-right:9%"></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-left:10%"></span>
        <label for="Label1" style="width:17%">Tax ID:</label>
        <select id="taxid" style="width:10%">
            <option value="fein">FEIN</option>
            <option value="ssn">SSN</option>
        </select>
        <label for="label2" style="color:red"><b>*</b></label>
        <span style="margin-left:20%"></span>
        <textarea asp-for="TaxID" style="width:30%; border-color: black" required placeholder="xxxxxxxxx" maxlength="9">@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Password)</textarea>
<text>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)</text>
```

In the above 2 line, I am having the following error:The type arguments for method 'TextAreaExtensions.TextAreaFor(HtmlHelper, Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
        <span style="margin-right:9%"></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-right:9%"></span>
        <label for="label6" style="color:darkblue; font-weight:normal !important">(Enter Federal Tax ID) or (SSN) 9 numbers, do not enter dashes or spaces.</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-right:9%"></span>
        <label for="label6" style="color:darkblue; font-weight:normal !important">If you don't know Email Address, then please call Helpdesk at 1-800-000-0000</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-left:20%"></span>
        <button type="submit" onclick="" style="width: 20%; color: white; background-color: deepskyblue; border-color:black"><b>Submit</b></button>
        <span style="margin-left:20%"></span>
        <button type="reset" style="width:20%; background-color:deepskyblue; color:white; border-color:black"><b>Clear</b></button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-left:10%"></span>
        <label for="label6" style="color:red; font-weight:normal !important; visibility: hidden">Email Address or the Login ID does not match. Please verify and enter the details again.</label>

    </form>
</body>
}
```

Global.asax has:

```
namespace WebApplicationTesting
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                "LoginPage",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "CorporationController", action = "LoginPage", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );            
        }
    }
}
```

The Model class is as follows:

```
public partial class Testing
    {
        public int LoginID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int TaxID { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CorporationName { get; set; }        
    }
```

Can someone help me with this. The page is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the method LIDAuthentication doesn't return a value the session value is null.

```
public ActionResult LIDAuthentication() 
{
    if (Session["LoginID"] != null)
    {
        return View();
    }

    return new RedirectToActionResult("action", "controller", null);
}
```

The page model is an IEnumerable containing Testing object, instead of one Testing object. It looks for a property on the IEnumerable that's not there

Change

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationTesting.Models.Testing>
```

to

```
@model WebApplicationTesting.Models.Testing
```

also check the code that call's the view so the model is correct

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix the error in controller class. I am still having four errors in the View.

Comment: @Harsha how does the model look like?

Comment: @Harsha I've updated the answer with a fix to the model issue

Comment: Awesome. I was able to get rid of all the errors. Right now, I am having a different issue with the same code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830483/page-not-redirecting-as-intended