# Page not redirecting as intended

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to validate input data and if the validation is true, go to the next view. However, I can see my code is not existing the present page.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ForgotLoginId()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ForgotLoginId(Testing ForgotLIDAuthentication)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using(SUPRTestingDBEntities2 db = new SUPRTestingDBEntities2())
                {
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        Session["LoginID"] = obj.EmailID.ToString();
                        Session["EmailID"] = obj.TaxID.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("LIDAuthentication");

                    }
                    else if (obj == null)
                    {
                        return View();
                    }
                }          
            }
            return View();
        }        

        public ActionResult LIDAuthentication()
        {
            if (Testing.IsUserValid())
            {
                return View();
            } 
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ForgotLoginID");
            }
        }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotLoginID", "Corporation", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
    <div style="border: 1px solid red">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
    }
<div>
<textarea name="EmailId" style="width:50%; border-color: black" required>@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.EmailID)</textarea>
        <text>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.EmailID)</text>
<textarea name="TaxID" style="width:30%; border-color: black" required placeholder="xxxxxxxxx" maxlength="9">@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Password)</textarea>
        <text>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)</text>
<button type="submit" style="width: 20%; color: white; background-color: deepskyblue; border-color:black" value="SubmitRequest" name="Submitbtn"><b>Submit</b></button>
</div>
}
```

Model:

```
public partial class Testing
    {
        public int LoginID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int TaxID { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CorporationName { get; set; }

        public static bool IsUserValid()
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context.Session["LoginID"] != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Here, the page not exiting the current view. When I tried to insert breakpoint after [httppost] in Controller, it is not even hitting the code.

Also, I am not sure why my view has something in fields, I don't know what it is. Not sure if this is affecting my output.

[ForgotLoginID View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8RZs.png)

Please help me with this.

Comment: It's odd that you have a <body> inside your <form>. Also, you're not showing the whole of your <form>, particularity not the submit button.input.

Comment: @JasperKent I have added the button to the view.

Comment: Also, you seem to be producing double <textarea>s. Html.TextAreaFor will produce a <textarea> in the generated HTML, so you don't need to wrap that up in your own <textarea>.

Comment: You have further problems in that you're not supplying the [Required] fields CorporationName and TaxId, but that should merely mean your ModelState.IsValid is false. 

I'm presuming your controller is correctly named CorporationController.

Comment: Yes, I can see my ModelState.IsValid is false, not allowing it to enter the initial if statement itself.

Comment: But you said it wasn't evening hitting the HttpPost method.

Comment: I am not sure what happened. It is now going until if (ModelState.IsValid) and jumping to return View().

Comment: That's because the changes in my answer fixed your initial problem. Now you have you have an additional problem that the model is invalid, for the reasons I explained regarding the missing required fields.

Comment: When you say missing required fields, do you mean declaring them as required in Model class? I have declared them as required.

Comment: You've declared them as required in the model, but your view has no code to provide values for them. Therefore they are empty when the model is created, and thus this model is invalid.

Comment: I guess I missing it big time. Can you help me with that?

Comment: The <form> in your view must provide fields for, at a minimum, all the required fields in your model. If you don't require those fields in these circumstances, then write a new model containing only what you need.

Comment: @JasperKent the model state error has been taken care of.Now it is coming as true after I made the changes to the fields in the VIew; @Html.TextAreaFor(Model => Model.Password). but, obj is still returns null.

Comment: `obj` isn't even declared in your code.

Comment: It worked. I didn't had to declare obj. instead, next to action result, i declared the EmailID and TaxID parameters.         public ActionResult ForgotLoginId(Testing ForgotLIDAuthentication, string EmailID, int TaxID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but your view code should look something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotLoginID", "Corporation", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div style="border: 1px solid red">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }

    @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.EmailID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.EmailID)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
    <button type="submit" style="width: 20%; color: white; background-color: deepskyblue; border-color:black" value="SubmitRequest" name="Submitbtn"><b>Submit</b></button>
}
```

Comment: How Can I add this message when the system validation fails and returns to the same page?  <label for="label6" style="color:red; font-weight:normal !important; visibility: hidden">Email Address or the Login ID does not match. Please verify and enter the details again.</label>

Comment: That looks like a separate question, so please post it as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852006/make-label-visible-when-validation-visible-in-asp-net-mvc