# Make Label visible when validation visible in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I click submit on view, the system redirects to a new view. If validation fails, the system redirects to the same page highlighting the fields. However, I also require the system to show a label with the error message.

```html
<label for="label6" style="color:red; font-weight:normal !important; visibility: hidden">
    The Corporate Email, FEIN or SSN does not match.<br /><br />
    <span style="margin-left: 10%"></span>The following might be the case:<br />
    <span style="margin-left: 12%"></span>- The Corporate Email entered is wrong. Please check the Corporate Email.<br />
    <span style="margin-left: 12%"></span>- The FEIN entered is wrong. Please check the FEIN.<br />
    <span style="margin-left: 12%"></span>- The SSN entered is wrong. Please check the SSN.<br />
    <span style="margin-left: 12%"></span>- Please verify whether FEIN or SSN entered during registration.<br />
    <span style="margin-left: 16%"></span>If you have registered using FEIN please submit using FEIN.<br />
    <span style="margin-left: 16%"></span>If you have registered using SSN please submit using SSN.<br />
</Label>
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: That's not going to do much good, since `visibility: hidden` means it can't be seen...Remove that if you want it to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to do it like that. Why tell them what the error might be when you can tell them what the error actually is?

In your view, after each `@Html.EditorFor` put a `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.EmailID)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.EmailID)
@Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Password)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
```

If your model state is invalid and you return to the view, the validation messages are automatically displayed for the invalid fields.

Going further, you can get the validation to be done using JavaScript in the browser, so that if the data is invalid the error message(s) will be displayed without needing a trip back to the server.

Simply add the following to the end of your view:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

(This assumes your site is based on the standard ASP.NET MVC template, and that you view uses a layout view. If not, you may have to do a bit of tweaking to get the correct JavaScript files.)

WARNING: Never rely solely on browser validation checking. It is there as a benefit to users so they get errors reported slightly faster. However, it is very easy for hackers to bypass browser checking, so always check the model state on the server as well.

Comment: That requirement is to tell them what could be the error. Yes, I do have the tags @Html.ValidationMessageFor() but, unable to display the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly that content, then in your controller, when the model is invalid, put

```
ViewBag.InvalidModel = true;
```

Then in your view put

```
@if(ViewBag.InvalidModel)
{
  <!-- Your label here-->
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do something
            return Redirect("/yournewpage");
        }

        if (!someChecks)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your custom error");
        }

        if (!someChecks2)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your custom error 2");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

You can use in view

```
<p>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<p>
```